# Incorrect amount of flags waiting for review

Tags: bug, flags

Here is an example:

[image]

The issue seems to be that spam flags are not counted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**6 waiting for review** is part of the **555 moderator attention flags**.

Spam, offensive and comment flags are apart.

Comment: So why are the two spam flags waiting for review not under the spam flags

Comment: A design choice, I presume. Spam, offensive and comment flags don't have this metric.